# Moving Python graphics.py objects

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to move two objects at the same time in python graphics (This seems to be referring to [John Zelle's graphics.py](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html)), then repeat the movement in a loop. However when I try to loop it, the shapes disappear. How can I fix this?

```
def main():
    win = GraphWin('Lab Four', 400, 400)
    c = Circle(Point(100, 50), 40)
    c.draw(win)
    c.setFill('red')
    s = Rectangle(Point(300, 300), Point(350, 350))
    s.draw(win)
    s.setFill('blue')
    s.getCenter()
    while not c.getCenter() == Circle(Point(400, 50), 40):
        c.move(10, 0)
        s.move(-10, 0)
    win.getMouse
    while not (win.checkMouse()):
        continue
    win.close()
```

Comment: Which graphics toolkit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of obvious problem with your code: you compare the center Point object of the circle against a circle object -- you need to compoare to a Point object; you left off the parentheses in your `win.getMouse()` call.  The rework below fixes these issues:

```
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400
RADIUS = 40

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Lab Four', WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    c = Circle(Point(100, 50), RADIUS)
    c.draw(win)
    c.setFill('red')

    s = Rectangle(Point(300, 300), Point(350, 350))
    s.draw(win)
    s.setFill('blue')

    while c.getCenter().getX() < WIDTH - RADIUS:
        c.move(10, 0)
        s.move(-10, 0)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Instead of comparing the center Point with a Point, I simply checked the X position since it's moving horizontally.

Comment: It moves too quickly - adding a time delay will show the movement.